# Expected number of draws w/replacement until both of the two classes appear

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, geometric-series

Suppose you draw repeatedly at random with replacement from a population in which a proportion $p$ of the individuals are in Class $A$ and the remaining proportion $q = 1-p$ in Class $B$. Let $D$ be the number of draws till both classes have appeared. Find $E(D)$ **by using the tail sum formula**.

EDIT: I am having difficulties approaching this problem. I am trying to frame it as the number of coin tosses until heads appear considering tails will have appeared before (assuming the first toss wasn't a success). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question by means of an edit (not a comment), and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$D$ is a random variable taking values in $\mathbb N$ and applying the tail sum formula we find: $$\mathbb ED=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(D> n)\tag1$$

Here event $\{D> n\}$ can be recognized as the event that the first chosen $n$ individuals are all of the same class.

So calculate the probability on these events, substitute in $(1)$ and calculate.